# Newbie - Downloads slow on wireless, long time to connect to wireless

Tags: wireless, downloads, download-speed

its taking a long time to connect to the wireless, and when it does, the internet in general seems unstable and really slow, like 45 mins to download a 50MB file on a 30MB connection. I switch to wired and get fab speeds.

I found a utility on another forum that got some info from linux, but as im a newbie at all this, I dont know if thats everything.

Thanks a lot in advance

http://pastebin.com/GU52nt1L

Comment: I also have 2 Windows machines that run on the wireless fine at good speeds so the issue is related to the laptop. also, I did have Windows on this laptop and the wireless worked fine but since I installed Linux its Been very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Are there other wireless devices nearby which use the same WiFi frequencies, but which are not WiFi? Wireless game controllers and wireless headsets are infamous for causing this, but baby monitors and 2.4GHz cordless phones can cause this as well.

Also try changing the frequency used by the wireless router. Typically, 1, 6 and 11 are the best to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Kismet or WICD. I really prefer WICD as I use it instead of Network Manager to connect to wifi when I am travelling.

You can download WICD or Kismet using Software Manager. If you want to use WICD then Download these 4 packages: WICD, WICD-Daemon, WICD-GTK and PYTHON WICD.

Then uninstall Network-Manager and Network-Manager-Gnome.

Reboot and look for WICD on your Menu. Open it and find a wifi connection you want to use. Enter the WEP or WPA information and the Security password and then connect.

You can use WICD to see which wifi connections. It will show you a graphic list of every connection and its strength. Its very easy to use I think it works much better than network manager.

Comment: I have installed WICD but I am having real problems with it. Its even slower than network manager and sometimes I cant connect at all with a bad password error, even though other times I can connect fine and I have changed no settings? When it does connect it takes a long time to obtain an IP address. Its strange as I have many other devices on both of my wireless connections and have no issues, its certainly ubuntu related. Any ideas please? Im sat right next to the routers so wireless quality is not an issue. Im typing this on the wired connection which is absolutely fine.